# What is different with function name in Constructor?

Tags: javascript, constructor

Hi I'm beginner learning javascript. What is difference between following 2 constructors?

```
function Animal(name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.walk = function walk(destination) { //here function has name 'walk'
                console.log(this.name,'is walking to',destination);
        };
}
```

and

```
function Animal(name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.walk = function (destination) { // but no function name
                console.log(this.name,'is walking to',destination);
        };
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Giving names to functions can help debugging. Otherwise, they behave pretty much the same.

Comment: Also, if you were to invoke `walk` recursively, you could refer to the function as `walk` within itself (as opposed to having to keep a separate reference).

Comment: The fact the function expression is inside a constructor function is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

Named function vs anonymous function - not much a difference. When an error will be thrown, you'll get more accurate stack trace with named functions.